# How to cluster over time?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model

I have a problem where I have a set of objects (say smartphones for ease of explanation). For each phone, we collected several characteristic features (such as duration of calls, how many calls made, received etc) over a period of 3 months (say). Now based on these collected datasets, we need to group the phones into clusters. The situation is kind of like in the following figure:
[image]

My first thought was to follow what we do during working with images. Make a vector out of the image matrix and then do the clustering. In my case, we make the vector by maintaining the temporal sequence. So for each phone, if the size of the dataset be m x p and there are n such phones, we build a dataset with size n x (m x p). However, I cannot decide if there is any problem with this approach or whether it will achieve what we want.

I am looking for some ideas.Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: It depends what you expect the clusters to represent. With your approach a cluster would take into account the pattern across time of the calls, so for instance it would consider the fact that two users have made many calls in the 2nd month as a similarity. If the goal is to group the phones by technical characteristics, it would make more sense to refactor the data in order to synthesize these characteristics independently from the user's behaviour.

Comment: Good comment. It is a bit vague at this point, but I am trying to obtain a clearer hypothesis. At this point, we expect to group the phones based on their "usage pattern". Now what would be usage pattern is not very clearly defined.

Comment: Another thought is to treat these as a tensor but didn't get anywhere with it yet.

Comment: If the behaviour across time is relevant then I guess your approach makes sense. The only potential technical issue is the high number of features.

Comment: yes, I agree. Number of features could potentially be 10,000 or more.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the clusters change over time, then the problem can be framed the problem is as time-series clustering. Almost all clustering algorithms have a time-series version (e.g., k-means and hierarchical).

If the clusters are assumed to be the same over time, then time can be ignored and standard clustering can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with simple feature engineering (min, max, avg, std) and simple exploration / embedding techniques.

If you want more advanced stuff I would start by embedding with umap, that allows time dependency of the data (https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aligned_umap_politics_demo.html) and to use complex model for embedding (https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parametric_umap.html).